# Ember.js. Filtered model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a model with tasks, and i wantto get data filtered by status and show result in different lists.

so i have a construction with does't work as i want.

```
    tasks: Ember.computed(function(){
        var modelTasks = this.get('store').findAll('task');

        return {
            todo: modelTasks.filterBy('status', 'todo'),
            inProgress: modelTasks.filterBy('status', 'inprogress'),
            done: modelTasks.filterBy('status', 'done')
        };
    }),
```

I'm new, so please be tolerant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need `tasks` computed property?. 
`findAll` returns Promise so your code is not correct. 
Async computed properties little tricky - read [this ignite article](https://emberigniter.com/guide-promises-computed-properties/) for more info.

I would say, data fetching should happen at the route level, so corresponding route js file `model` hook you can write,

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.get('store').findAll('task').then((result) => {
            return {
                todo: result.filterBy('status', 'todo'),
                inProgress: result.filterBy('status', 'inprogress'),
                done: result.filterBy('status', 'done')
            };
        });
    }
});
```

inside corresponding hbs file, you can access it like `model.todo`